# Contempt factor

Tags: engines, draw, evaluation

I have a question concerning the contempt factor of a chess engine, that i am writing, and thought that this forum would be the best one to ask it in. The contempt factor is a way of deincentivizing the engine from accepting a draw if it is winning and vice versa. I have read an article on the Chess programming wiki called "Pawn Advantage, Win Percentage, and Elo", where they gave an equation for the statistical win probability as a function of the pawn advantage (the +/- number given from an engine),

[image]

Where W is the probability of winning as a function of the pawn advantage (relative to the side in question).

I have thought about using this formula to give a drawn position a bad score if the engine is up a lot of material by for example scoring repetitions and fifty-moves as -10*W such that if the engine has a 70% probability of winning, it will get a big penalty for drawing the game.

Since i have not seen any similar implementations i dont know if it is a good idea or not, so my question is: What do you guys think about this? Do you think this will give too large penalties for drawing the game or could it possibly make the engine stronger?

Comment: I don't see the point of this tbh. If the engine wants to draw DESPITE being up in material then the opponent must have some serious initiative/threats to make the engine want to make a draw anyway. In that case, well, you're probably better off letting the engine make a draw.